# Play QTMovie in ScreenSaver for Cocoa/OSX

Tags: cocoa, macos, movie, screensaver, qtkit

I'm trying to create a screen saver that will play a QTMovie, in the ScreenSaverView class. I think I have to use QTMovieView, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to create and initialize the QTMovieView object without using interface builder (as I undertand it, it's not possible to use interface builder when making a .saver file with the ScreenSaverView class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could poke around at the source of this one:
http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/SaveHollywood.html